# Chrome latest beta update: SSL certificate warning

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

After updating to ***Google Chrome Version 39 beta*** `green lock` for some of my `https` connections (domains hosted by me) has turned to be one with `yellow triangle` on it.

When clicking for additional details, it returns the following *message/warning*:

[image]

The certificates are up to date and valid until late *2018* and shown correctly (green) in all other browsers including Chrome up until version `38`.

There is nothing that was tweaked/changed recently, neither on Apache server nor SSL certificates.

Something has been changed on Chrome but *what* and *why*?

How do I *fix it* to prevent possible problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SHA-1 Sunsetting, Google, and your next steps.**

Google recently made an announcement, in stark contrast to Microsoft's plan, that they are implementing their own SHA-1 sunsetting timeline, which will begin on September 26th 2014.

**Why?**

First, let's understand what SHA-1 does. Both SHA-1 and its successor, SHA-2, are specific types of signing algorithms. Signing algorithms are used as part of the identity validation role that SSL certificates perform. They are mathematical functions (referred to as a "hash") which, when performed, should calculate a persistent and unique value for each file. So, for instance, the Word doc this text is stored in has a unique SHA-1 hash value. If I change a single part of this file – add an extra period somewhere, change a letter, etc. – it will produce a different SHA-1 hash value.

When a certificate is downloaded from a server to the client's browser, a hash is taken of it. The type of hash taken (SHA-1, SHA-2, MD5, etc.) depends on how the certificate is signed. The hash calculated by the browser is compared to the hash value provided by the server, which has been verified by the Certificate Authority (CA) at the time of issuance. If they match, the identity of the certificate and server are verified.

**When is this happening?**

Google's policy involves three distinct steps, the first beginning on *September 26th*. On this date, only customers with SHA-1 signed certificates expiring in 2017 are affected. However, the amount of affected certificates **will expand in November**, and again in Q1 2015. The full details on what certificates are affected is in the below section, "The Nitty Gritty."

**What certificates are affected?**

Certificates are affected if they meet the any of the following criteria:

- All certificates from the RapidSSL or QuickSSL family issued before September 15th, 2014 and expiring after January 31st, 2016 (They are signed by a SHA-1 Intermediate).
- If they are signed with SHA-1 and expire after January 1st, 2016.
- They have an Intermediate Certificate Chain that are SHA-1 signed certificates.
  To understand the exact certificates affected, please see the below section which gives explicit detail.

**On September 26th, 2014** SHA-1 signed certificates expiring on or after January 1st, 2017 will be treated as "secure, but with minor errors" and will receive the yellow triangle padlock.

[image]

**On November 7th, 2014** SHA-1 signed certificates expiring on or after June 1st, 2016 to December 31st, 2016 are treated as above. Certificates expiring after January 1st, 2017 are treated as "neutral, lacking security." These certificates will receive a blank page icon, as seen with HTTP sessions.
[image]

**In Q1 2015** SHA-1 signed certificates expiring on or after January 1st, 2016 to December 31st, 2016 will continue to be treated as "secure, but with minor errors. "SHA-1 signed certificates that expire on or after January 1st, 2017 are treated as "affirmatively insecure." This will be identified by the red "X".
[image]

---

**How is the problem solved?**

Affected certificates can be fixed by reissuing (There are no situations where anything other than a reissue is needed). Our partner CAs have sped up their implementation of SHA-2 compatible infrastructure due to Google's new policy.

**What do I need to do?**

If your certificate is SHA-1, you need to perform the following:

1. ***A reissue of your certificate to SHA-2***

In addition to the step above, you probably also need to:

2. ***Install newly available SHA-2 Intermediate Certificates***.

If your certificate was SHA-1, most likely ***it was also signed by a SHA-1 Intermediate***. When you reissue the certificate it will be signed by the SHA-2 Intermediate, which must also be installed to your server. These will either be provided or linked to you when you receive your new certificate.

> **[Check your site for weak SHA-1 certificates](https://shaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com)**
>
> **[SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest)**
>
> **[SHA1 Deprecation: What You Need to Know](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/09/09/sha1-deprecation-what-you-need-to-know)**